# Scraping Android Store

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape Android Store pages with Beautiful Soup in order to have a file that contains a list of packages.
Here is my code :

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import time

url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/topselling_free'
response = get(url)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(html_soup)

app_container = html_soup.find_all('div', class_="card no-rationale 
square-cover apps small")
file = open("applications.txt","w+")
for i in range(0,60):
#if range > 60 ; "IndexError: list index out of range"
    print(app_container[i].div['data-docid'])
    file.write(app_container[i].div['data-docid'] + "\n")

file.close()
```

The problem is that I can only collect 60 packages names because the javascript isn't loaded and if I have to load more apps I have to scrolldown. How can I reproduce this behaviour in Python to have more than 60 results ?

Answer (score 1):

Would you consider a more fully featured scraper? Scrapy is purpose-built for the job: https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/06/22/scrapy-tips-from-the-pros-june-2016

Selenium is like driving a browser with code - if you can do it in person you can probably do it in selenium: [scrape websites with infinite scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519074/scrape-websites-with-infinite-scrolling)

Others have concluded that bs4 and requests is not enough for the task: [How to load all entries in an infinite scroll at once to parse the HTML in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006940/how-to-load-all-entries-in-an-infinite-scroll-at-once-to-parse-the-html-in-pytho)

Also note that scraping can be a bit of a grey area and that you should always try to be aware and respectful of site policies. Their TOS and robots.txt are always good places to peruse.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use Scrapy with Splash

http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-tutorial.html.

Splash is a headless browser and you can render JS and execute Scripts. Some code sample

```
function main(splash)
    local num_scrolls = 10
    local scroll_delay = 1.0

    local scroll_to = splash:jsfunc("window.scrollTo")
    local get_body_height = splash:jsfunc(
        "function() {return document.body.scrollHeight;}"
    )
    assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
    splash:wait(splash.args.wait)

    for _ = 1, num_scrolls do
        scroll_to(0, get_body_height())
        splash:wait(scroll_delay)
    end        
    return splash:html()
end
```

To render this script use 'execute' endpoint instead of render.html endpoint:

```
script = """<Lua script> """
scrapy_splash.SplashRequest(url, self.parse,
                            endpoint='execute', 
                            args={'wait':2, 'lua_source': script}, ...)
```

I am using Scrapy for Crawling and i believe you need to run the Crawling periodically.  you can use Scrapyd for running the Scrapy spider.

I got this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325657/how-does-scrapy-splash-handle-infinite-scrolling)